# Merge/rebase a 'disconnected' branch in Git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Suppose we have the following situation in Git:

```
      X---Y feature
     /
A---B---C---D edge
```

Now I rebase the `edge` branch changing the B commit a little bit (using `edit`) so it now looks like this:

```
      X---Y feature

A---E---C'---D' edge
```

C' and D' are the same commits as C and D, but applied on top of E (and notice that X within the `feature` branch became disconnected).

Now how can I:

1. Rebase/merge the `feature` branch so that its commits appear as if they were applied on top of D'?
2. Rebase/merge the `feature` branch so that its commits appear as if they were applied on top of E, but without a separate 'merging branch ...' commit (and with C' and D' being rewritten to become C'' and D'')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X` doesn't become disconnected per-se, it still has the original `B` as its parent. If you want to subsequently rebase `feature` on top of `edge`, then:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase edge
```

If you wish to change the tree so that it has a similar structure to the original version, but with `X` as a child of `E`, that's:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto <sha-of-E> <sha-of-B> feature
```