# How do I reconnect a Git branch that has separated from master? (And duplicated its parents?)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

This is a complicated situation, but essentially what has happened here is that our branch has become separated from master.  So essentially:

```
A - B - C          master
     \
      X - Y - Z    feature
```

has turned into:

```
A - B - C          master

(A) - (B) - X - Y - Z  feature
```

The SHAs are the same for A/(A) and B/(B). This is exactly how it appears in GitK. At this point, I'm just trying to essentially put it back in the same order it was previously.  Unfortunately, since the SHAs appear to be identical, I don't know how I can manipulate X to branch out of B instead of (B). I honestly don't know where to begin attempting this recovery.  How can I reconnect the two branches at commit B?

Note that I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349928/merge-rebase-a-disconnected-branch-in-git) but it seems to be a slightly different issue, because the sha-1 of B and (B) are the same, since it has not been changed.

Comment: What does `git merge-base <C> <X>` return?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how this actually happened?

Comment: If the sha-1s of (B) and B are the same, doesn't this mean that it is, in fact, connected?

Comment: See how it looks in `gitk --all`.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in GitK? What other Git GUIs like SmartGit show?

Comment: I believe this happened when someone tried to repair by forcing a local branch push to a remote.  It seems that it pushed the entire history, and gitk shows them as separate.  gitk --all DOES seem to work, but unfortunately, the remote feature branch shows the full history as specific to the branch, AND the remote master branch shows the full master branch as if it's specific to master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure the A/(A) and B/(B) are the same SHA hash, then I don't see what the issue is, as X's parent is B === (B) according to your diagram.

Is this all on a local repository? Are there any remote bare repositories involved?

Try running from the following to show the graph and put it in your question:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

I replicated your setup with simple pushes and commits and this command gives (from the feature branch) :

```
* 86bf1b1 added Y on feature
* a690031 added X on feature
| * a7347fe added C on master
|/  
* d02c518 added B
* 7d81e39 added A
```

If the SHA commits are as you suggest, you should see the same behaviour. If not, post an update with the isolated area you see at issue.

Comment: Agreed, if sha1's are same, it means they are same, the only option comes to my mind is that remote tracking might be broken and (A) and (B) has not been committed since, but branched out locally.

Comment: Using git log --graph --oneline --all DOES appear to show the correct tree.  I'm not sure why I thought it was different yesterday.  Perhaps there was a merge that caused the trees to join, that was rebased.  Thank you for the assistance.